Spotify Audio picker intent android
I have to change the background music in my app, I want to pick an audio from spotify. On button click in our app it will open spotify song browser screen and Here user can browse music and can select any music from spotify and then selected music will get played inside our app. How to achieve this ?
Is there any App or SDK that allows us to select their online music?
